# Conditionally populating a column with a row value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set of wages for male and female workers indicated by there name.

```
 Male     Female    Male_Wage  Female_Wage
 James     Lori        8            9
 Mike      Nancy       10           8
 Ron       Cathy       11           12
 Jon       Ruth        15           9
 Jason     Jackie      10           10
```

In pandas I would like to create a new column in the data frame that displays the name of the person that is the highest paid. If the condition exists that both are paid the same the value should be Same.

```
     Male     Female    Male_Wage  Female_Wage  Highest_Paid
     James     Lori        8            9          Lori
     Mike      Nancy       10           8          Mike
     Ron       Cathy       11           12         Cathy
     Jon       Ruth        15           9          Jon
     Jason     Jackie      10           10         Same
```

I have been able to add a column and populate it with values, calculate a value based on other columns etc. but not how to fill the new column conditionally based on the value of another column with the condition of same in the instance the wages are the same is causing me trouble. I have searched for an answer quite a bit and have not found anything that covers all the elements of this situation.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `loc` statements

```
df.loc[df['Male_Wage'] == df['Female_Wage'], 'Highest_Paid'] = 'Same'
df.loc[df['Male_Wage'] > df['Female_Wage'], 'Highest_Paid'] = df['Male']
df.loc[df['Male_Wage'] < df['Female_Wage'], 'Highest_Paid'] = df['Female']
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Method 1: `np.select`:

We can specify our condtions and based on those condition, we get the values of `Male` or `Female`, else `default='Same'`

```
conditions = [
    df['Male_Wage'] > df['Female_Wage'],
    df['Female_Wage'] > df['Male_Wage']
]

choices = [df['Male'], df['Female']]

df['Highest_Paid'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='Same')

    Male  Female  Male_Wage  Female_Wage Highest_Paid
0  James    Lori          8            9         Lori
1   Mike   Nancy         10            8         Mike
2    Ron   Cathy         11           12        Cathy
3    Jon    Ruth         15            9          Jon
4  Jason  Jackie         10           10         Same
```

---

#### Method 2: `np.where` + `loc`

Using `np.where` and `.loc` to conditionally assign the correct value:

```
df['Highest_Paid'] = np.where(df['Male_Wage'] > df['Female_Wage'], 
                              df['Male'], 
                              df['Female'])

df.loc[df['Male_Wage'] == df['Female_Wage'], 'Highest_Paid'] = 'Same'

    Male  Female  Male_Wage  Female_Wage Highest_Paid
0  James    Lori          8            9         Lori
1   Mike   Nancy         10            8         Mike
2    Ron   Cathy         11           12        Cathy
3    Jon    Ruth         15            9          Jon
4  Jason  Jackie         10           10         Same
```